# Need help displaying 4D data in matplotlib 3D scatterplot properly

Tags: matplotlib, visualization, heatmap, scatter-plot, graphing

Hey so I'm an undergraduate working in an imaging lab and I have a 3D numpy array that has values from 0-9 to indicate concentration in a 3D space. I'm trying to plot these values in a scatterplot with a colormap to indicate the value between 0-9. The array is 256 x 256 x 48, so I feel like the size of it is making it difficult for me to plot the array in a meaningful way.

I've attached a picture of what it looks like right now. As you can see the concentration looks very "faded" even for very high values and I'm not entirely sure why. Here is the code I'm using to generate the plot:

current heatmap

[image: 1]

```
fig = plt.figure()

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(range(256), range(256), range(48))

col = sum_array.flatten()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

sc = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c = col, cmap='Reds', 
    linewidths=.01, s=.03, vmin=0, vmax=9, 
    marker='.', alpha=1)

plt.colorbar(sc)

plt.show()
```

If anyone can help me display the colors in a more bright/concentrated manner so the heat map is visually useful, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: without proper running example (``sum_array`` is not available), I cannot recreate the problem. I substituted ``col = sum_array.flatten()`` with ``col = np.random.randint(10, size=256*256*48)`` and the result is pretty clear. PS: your linewidth is most probably the ploblem, it's far too small.

Comment: I would also suggest that the one of the main reasons it looks faded is that the marker size of 0.03 is too small. If you increase this I expect that it will make the density of points look more as expected. But, seeing as your `alpha` value is 1, i.e., all points are opaque, if you have points with a `col` value of 1 surrounding points of `col` value 9, then it may still look faded. This is going to be intrinsic to trying to do what you want in 3d. Maybe just doing several 2d plots of slices through the distribution would work better?